# Storm topology does not start processing

Tags: apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I am launching a Storm v1.0.1 cluster with 1 nimbus and 4 supervisor nodes. I have 2 zookeeper nodes. When I try to launch a sample Topology which should be consuming from Kafka. However upon inspecting nimbus and supervisor logs after the topolgy has been submitted, I discovered that workers are not launching.

storm.yaml

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
    - "storage14"
    - "storage16"

nimbus.host: "storage01"
nimbus.seeds : ["storage01"]

storm.local.dir: "/tmp/storm"

supervisor.slots.ports:
    - 6700

worker.heap.memory.mb: 8192
supervisor.memory.capacity.mb: 10240
```

Nimbus log:

```
2016-12-26 03:28:47.921 o.a.s.s.EvenScheduler [INFO] Available slots: (["c941fac0-be93-4ea3-8a39-c316a8430112" 6700] ["fc35bd75-dd24-49fc-af90-e6493cdb1e8f" 6700] ["3363bfc3-4083-4a25-af82-0709f43e73cb" 6700] ["9edace71-d7b6-42d1-a7bd-964851669a17" 6700])
2016-12-26 03:28:47.972 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Setting new assignment for topology id identity-1-1482740925: #org.apache.storm.daemon.common.Assignment{:master-code-dir "/tmp/storm", :node->host {"c941fac0-be93-4ea3-8a39-c316a8430112" "storage02", "9edace71-d7b6-42d1-a7bd-964851669a17" "storage03", "fc35bd75-dd24-49fc-af90-e6493cdb1e8f" "storage05", "3363bfc3-4083-4a25-af82-0709f43e73cb" "storage04"}, :executor->node+port {[8 8] ["9edace71-d7b6-42d1-a7bd-964851669a17" 6700], [12 12] ["9edace71-d7b6-42d1-a7bd-964851669a17" 6700], [2 2] ["fc35bd75-dd24-49fc-af90-e6493cdb1e8f" 6700], [32 32] ["9edace71-d7b6-42d1-a7bd-964851669a17" 6700], [7 7] ["3363bfc3-4083-4a25-af82-0709f43e73cb" 6700], [22 22] ["fc35bd75-dd24-49fc-af90-e6493cdb1e8f" 6700], [3 3] ["3363bfc3-4083-4a25-af82-0709f43e73cb" 6700], [33 33] ["c941fac0-be93-4ea3-8a39-c316a8430112" 6700], [24 24] ["9edace71-d7b6-42d1-a7bd-964851669a17" 6700], [1 1] ["c941fac0-be93-4ea3-8a39-c316a8430112" 6700], [35 35] ["3363bfc3-4083-4a25-af82-0709f43e73cb" 6700], [18 18] ["fc35bd75-dd24-49fc-af90-e6493cdb1e8f" 6700], [6 6] ["fc35bd75-dd24-49fc-af90-e6493cdb1e8f" 6700], [28 28] ["9edace71-d7b6-42d1-a7bd-964851669a17" 6700], [20 20] ["9edace71-d7b6-42d1-a7bd-964851669a17" 6700], [9 9] ["c941fac0-be93-4ea3-8a39-c316a8430112" 6700], [30 30] ["fc35bd75-dd24-49fc-af90-e6493cdb1e8f" 6700], [23 23] ["3363bfc3-4083-4a25-af82-0709f43e73cb" 6700], [11 11] ["3363bfc3-4083-4a25-af82-0709f43e73cb" 6700], [31 31] ["3363bfc3-4083-4a25-af82-0709f43e73cb" 6700], [16 16] ["9edace71-d7b6-42d1-a7bd-964851669a17" 6700], [13 13] ["c941fac0-be93-4ea3-8a39-c316a8430112" 6700], [19 19] ["3363bfc3-4083-4a25-af82-0709f43e73cb" 6700], [21 21] ["c941fac0-be93-4ea3-8a39-c316a8430112" 6700], [5 5] ["c941fac0-be93-4ea3-8a39-c316a8430112" 6700], [27 27] ["3363bfc3-4083-4a25-af82-0709f43e73cb" 6700], [29 29] ["c941fac0-be93-4ea3-8a39-c316a8430112" 6700], [26 26] ["fc35bd75-dd24-49fc-af90-e6493cdb1e8f" 6700], [10 10] ["fc35bd75-dd24-49fc-af90-e6493cdb1e8f" 6700], [14 14] ["fc35bd75-dd24-49fc-af90-e6493cdb1e8f" 6700], [4 4] ["9edace71-d7b6-42d1-a7bd-964851669a17" 6700], [36 36] ["9edace71-d7b6-42d1-a7bd-964851669a17" 6700], [15 15] ["3363bfc3-4083-4a25-af82-0709f43e73cb" 6700], [34 34] ["fc35bd75-dd24-49fc-af90-e6493cdb1e8f" 6700], [25 25] ["c941fac0-be93-4ea3-8a39-c316a8430112" 6700], [17 17] ["c941fac0-be93-4ea3-8a39-c316a8430112" 6700]}, :executor->start-time-secs {[8 8] 1482740927, [12 12] 1482740927, [2 2] 1482740927, [32 32] 1482740927, [7 7] 1482740927, [22 22] 1482740927, [3 3] 1482740927, [33 33] 1482740927, [24 24] 1482740927, [1 1] 1482740927, [35 35] 1482740927, [18 18] 1482740927, [6 6] 1482740927, [28 28] 1482740927, [20 20] 1482740927, [9 9] 1482740927, [30 30] 1482740927, [23 23] 1482740927, [11 11] 1482740927, [31 31] 1482740927, [16 16] 1482740927, [13 13] 1482740927, [19 19] 1482740927, [21 21] 1482740927, [5 5] 1482740927, [27 27] 1482740927, [29 29] 1482740927, [26 26] 1482740927, [10 10] 1482740927, [14 14] 1482740927, [4 4] 1482740927, [36 36] 1482740927, [15 15] 1482740927, [34 34] 1482740927, [25 25] 1482740927, [17 17] 1482740927}, :worker->resources {["c941fac0-be93-4ea3-8a39-c316a8430112" 6700] [0.0 0.0 0.0], ["fc35bd75-dd24-49fc-af90-e6493cdb1e8f" 6700] [0.0 0.0 0.0], ["9edace71-d7b6-42d1-a7bd-964851669a17" 6700] [0.0 0.0 0.0], ["3363bfc3-4083-4a25-af82-0709f43e73cb" 6700] [0.0 0.0 0.0]}}
2016-12-26 03:28:48.123 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Created download session for identity-1-1482740925-stormjar.jar with id 880ba380-ace1-4622-8765-f1bdd977b57d
2016-12-26 03:28:48.127 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Created download session for identity-1-1482740925-stormjar.jar with id 6f0ccc65-6968-4bda-8cc6-13b719e44128
2016-12-26 03:28:48.132 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Created download session for identity-1-1482740925-stormjar.jar with id 14cb58cd-45b2-4f75-bbd1-3aa20a6cc76f
2016-12-26 03:28:48.142 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Created download session for identity-1-1482740925-stormjar.jar with id 3b7100e6-9a4a-44b2-a5ec-2637da91453f
2016-12-26 03:28:48.762 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Created download session for identity-1-1482740925-stormcode.ser with id 1e0546d8-43e7-4422-8290-b00d6e8856da
2016-12-26 03:28:48.767 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Created download session for identity-1-1482740925-stormcode.ser with id 16137c26-eb4d-4000-bda0-658197b30e2f
2016-12-26 03:28:48.772 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Created download session for identity-1-1482740925-stormconf.ser with id a939e4b1-0f52-4abc-8456-0fb504307221
2016-12-26 03:28:48.777 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Created download session for identity-1-1482740925-stormcode.ser with id 2d8d4769-14a8-490c-9737-5c4cf34d0e2d
2016-12-26 03:28:48.783 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Created download session for identity-1-1482740925-stormconf.ser with id 49728932-320c-4a05-acbf-cae872d10651
2016-12-26 03:28:48.789 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Created download session for identity-1-1482740925-stormconf.ser with id 13513809-a15c-43e0-8cbc-c4ac3b43f23e
2016-12-26 03:28:48.873 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Created download session for identity-1-1482740925-stormcode.ser with id 07f54afe-695e-4253-bb3b-04c9701d0578
2016-12-26 03:28:48.881 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Created download session for identity-1-1482740925-stormconf.ser with id 1bc067a0-f88d-459e-bb92-9d92535d5bb8
2016-12-26 03:30:49.418 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[8 8] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.418 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[12 12] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.418 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[2 2] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.419 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[32 32] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.419 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[7 7] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.419 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[22 22] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.419 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[3 3] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.419 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[33 33] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.419 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[24 24] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.419 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[1 1] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.419 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[35 35] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.420 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[18 18] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.420 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[6 6] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.420 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[28 28] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.420 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[20 20] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.420 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[9 9] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.420 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[30 30] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.420 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[23 23] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.420 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[11 11] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.421 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[31 31] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.421 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[16 16] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.421 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[13 13] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.421 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[19 19] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.421 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[21 21] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.421 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[5 5] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.421 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[27 27] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.422 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[29 29] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.422 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[26 26] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.422 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[10 10] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.422 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[14 14] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.422 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[4 4] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.422 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[36 36] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.422 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[15 15] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.422 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[34 34] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.423 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[25 25] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.423 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Executor identity-1-1482740925:[17 17] not alive
2016-12-26 03:30:49.447 o.a.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Setting new assignment for topology id identity-1-1482740925: #org.apache.storm.daemon.common.Assignment{:master-code-dir "/tmp/storm", :node->host {}, :executor->node+port {}, :executor->start-time-secs {[8 8] 1482740927, [12 12] 1482740927, [2 2] 1482740927, [32 32] 1482740927, [7 7] 1482740927, [22 22] 1482740927, [3 3] 1482740927, [33 33] 1482740927, [24 24] 1482740927, [1 1] 1482740927, [35 35] 1482740927, [18 18] 1482740927, [6 6] 1482740927, [28 28] 1482740927, [20 20] 1482740927, [9 9] 1482740927, [30 30] 1482740927, [23 23] 1482740927, [11 11] 1482740927, [31 31] 1482740927, [16 16] 1482740927, [13 13] 1482740927, [19 19] 1482740927, [21 21] 1482740927, [5 5] 1482740927, [27 27] 1482740927, [29 29] 1482740927, [26 26] 1482740927, [10 10] 1482740927, [14 14] 1482740927, [4 4] 1482740927, [36 36] 1482740927, [15 15] 1482740927, [34 34] 1482740927, [25 25] 1482740927, [17 17] 1482740927}, :worker->resources {}}
```

Supervisor log:

```
2016-12-26 03:30:49.362 o.a.s.config [INFO] GET worker-user ace3c157-ec78-49f9-af52-0f78d62bd29f
2016-12-26 03:30:49.369 o.a.s.config [INFO] REMOVE worker-user ace3c157-ec78-49f9-af52-0f78d62bd29f
2016-12-26 03:30:49.369 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] Shut down 9edace71-d7b6-42d1-a7bd-964851669a17:ace3c157-ec78-49f9-af52-0f78d62bd29f
2016-12-26 03:30:49.370 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] Launching worker with assignment {:storm-id "identity-1-1482740925", :executors [[8 8] [12 12] [32 32] [24 24] [28 28] [20 20] [16 16] [4 4] [36 36]], :resources #object[org.apache.storm.generated.WorkerResources 0x7b1ae274 "WorkerResources(mem_on_heap:0.0, mem_off_heap:0.0, cpu:0.0)"]} for this supervisor 9edace71-d7b6-42d1-a7bd-964851669a17 on port 6700 with id 14ce240d-5ef3-43be-9cb8-752ef73333cf
2016-12-26 03:30:49.385 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] Launching worker with command: '/opt/java/1.7.0//bin/java' '-cp' '/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/reflectasm-1.10.1.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/clojure-1.7.0.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/minlog-1.3.0.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/storm-rename-hack-1.0.1.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/objenesis-2.1.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/disruptor-3.3.2.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/storm-core-1.0.1.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/log4j-core-2.1.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/kryo-3.0.3.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/conf:/tmp/storm/supervisor/stormdist/identity-1-1482740925/stormjar.jar' '-Xmx64m' '-Dlogfile.name=worker.log' '-Dstorm.home=/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1' '-Dworkers.artifacts=/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/logs/workers-artifacts' '-Dstorm.id=identity-1-1482740925' '-Dworker.id=14ce240d-5ef3-43be-9cb8-752ef73333cf' '-Dworker.port=6700' '-Dstorm.log.dir=/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/logs' '-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/log4j2/worker.xml' '-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.BasicContextSelector' 'org.apache.storm.LogWriter' '/opt/java/1.7.0//bin/java' '-server' '-Xmx8192m' '-XX:+PrintGCDetails' '-Xloggc:artifacts/gc.log' '-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps' '-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps' '-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation' '-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10' '-XX:GCLogFileSize=1M' '-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError' '-XX:HeapDumpPath=artifacts/heapdump' '-Djava.library.path=/tmp/storm/supervisor/stormdist/identity-1-1482740925/resources/Linux-amd64:/tmp/storm/supervisor/stormdist/identity-1-1482740925/resources:/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib' '-Dlogfile.name=worker.log' '-Dstorm.home=/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1' '-Dworkers.artifacts=/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/logs/workers-artifacts' '-Dstorm.conf.file=' '-Dstorm.options=' '-Dstorm.log.dir=/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/logs' '-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/storm/workers/14ce240d-5ef3-43be-9cb8-752ef73333cf/tmp' '-Dlogging.sensitivity=S3' '-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/log4j2/worker.xml' '-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.BasicContextSelector' '-Dstorm.id=identity-1-1482740925' '-Dworker.id=14ce240d-5ef3-43be-9cb8-752ef73333cf' '-Dworker.port=6700' '-cp' '/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/reflectasm-1.10.1.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/clojure-1.7.0.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/minlog-1.3.0.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/storm-rename-hack-1.0.1.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/objenesis-2.1.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/disruptor-3.3.2.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/storm-core-1.0.1.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/listreaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/kryo-3.0.3.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar:/home/javed.19/git-pull/finished/streaming-benchmarks/apache-storm-1.0.1/conf:/tmp/storm/supervisor/stormdist/identity-1-1482740925/stormjar.jar' 'org.apache.storm.daemon.worker' 'identity-1-1482740925' '3363bfc3-4083-4a25-af82-0709f43e73cb' '6700' '5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10'
2016-12-26 03:30:49.316 o.a.s.config [INFO] SET worker-user 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 javed.19
2016-12-26 03:30:49.316 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] Creating symlinks for worker-id: 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 storm-id: identity-1-1482740925 to its port artifacts directory
2016-12-26 03:30:49.325 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] Creating symlinks for worker-id: 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 storm-id: identity-1-1482740925 for files(1): ("resources")
2016-12-26 03:30:49.329 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:49.829 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:49.849 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] Worker Process 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 exited with code: 1
2016-12-26 03:30:50.329 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:50.830 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:51.330 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:51.830 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:52.331 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:52.831 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:53.331 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:53.832 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:54.332 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:54.832 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:55.333 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:55.833 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:56.333 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:56.834 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:57.334 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:57.834 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:58.335 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:58.835 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:59.335 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:30:59.836 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:00.336 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:00.837 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:01.337 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:01.837 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:02.338 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:02.838 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:03.338 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:03.839 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:04.339 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:04.839 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:05.340 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:05.840 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:06.340 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:06.841 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:07.341 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:07.841 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:08.342 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:08.842 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:09.342 o.a.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 5fbae825-35ee-45f6-bced-f91a73037e10 still hasn't started
2016-12-26 03:31:09.813 o.a.s.u.NimbusClient [WARN] Using deprecated config nimbus.host for backward compatibility. Please update your storm.yaml so it only has config nimbus.seeds
```

Also I have confirmed that nimbus and supervisors are reachable from each other. What else could be causing this issue ?

P.S: You might wonder why I have both `nimbus.host` and `nimbus.seeds` property in my storm.yaml. If I only use `numbs.seeds`, Storm UI does not detect any nimbus saying :
`Found nimbuses [] none of which is elected as leader, please try again after some time.`

Comment: I assume that `storm.zookeeper.servers` point to healthy zookeeper hosts and nimbus can access the root node `/storm`?  Does zookeeper root `/storm` contain all of your supervisors? Is `storage1` a recognised, resolvable _host_ name?

Comment: Seems like supervisor tried to launch the worker but launching command returns exit code 1 which is abnormal. Could you check this line from log "Launching worker with command: " and see there're any bad things on launching command?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the worker processes not starting properly on supervisor nodes. Storm was trying to start worker VMs with certain GC log parameters by default. Changing the storm.yaml to start worker processes without these params fixed the issue.